# Is Process same as Main-Thread in execution?

Tags: operating-system

Is there any concrete difference between Process and the Main-Thread in execution.

I've read about the differences between Process and thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple ways to look at it. The 2 most common are:

a) A process is just a container (that contains things like a virtual address space, file descriptors, and one or more threads); and the scheduler only schedules threads. In this case, saying that a process is the same as a main thread is like saying that a plastic lunch box (container) is the same as a sandwich (contents).

b) There are tasks, and the scheduler schedules tasks. Tasks may share none, some or all resources (virtual address space, file descriptors). To emulate "single-threaded process" a task doesn't share resources, to emulate "multi-threaded process" 2 or more tasks share the same resources, and to emulate something in-between 2 or more tasks share some but not all resources. In this case, saying that a process is the same as a main thread is a little bit like saying that a piece of toast is the same as a sandwich (they're both types of food and they're both made from bread, in the same way that processes and threads are both types of concurrency and both made from tasks).

Note: I prefer the first way of looking at it - it's what most programmers expect, avoids confusion and work-arounds in the kernel (e.g. code to try to figure out if "task ID" should pretend to be "process ID" or "thread ID"), and nobody cares about the extra flexibility (e.g. the "some but not all resources shared" possibility). I consider the second way of looking at it to be "antiquated" (e.g. from a time when people were trying to "retro-fit" support for multi-threading on top of older operating systems where the existing scheduler scheduled processes).

Comment: Just a followup question.. 
When we start some application (eg: Microsoft word), as a programmer point of view we can say that the main thread started. Now, does the operating system decides on what resources should be allocated to this thread (like memory etc to make it a process and start) or does the application has to intimate the operating system on its resource requirements? 
Also, can you share some links where I can get to know, how the process will be created when main thread starts execution.

Comment: @Sumedha: For Microsoft stuff; I'd expect `CreateProcessA()` constructs the container (virtual address space, etc) and then calls a different function (`CreateThread()`) to start the process' main thread. Of course it's significantly more complicated than that (e.g. things like figuring out which executable file format and which executable loader to use, which libraries the executable uses, doing dynamic linking, etc). Also; there's typically "system libraries" involved so that the kernel can be radically changed (and the system library modified to suit) without breaking the application.

Comment: In this way; I'd expect that the executable itself doesn't know much about the OS, but the system library (and executable loader, etc) does. I don't know of any good links (maybe a tutorial on OS design?).